# How to get the current frame of a animation_frame in dash python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to get the current value of a animation frame and then to print it in my python terminal but also to show it in the website, how can I do that ?

I already tried to output it was a callback in a html.Div but it dosent work. I got this error:

Property "animation_frame" was used with component ID:
"graph-pos"
in one of the Input items of a callback.
This ID is assigned to a dash_core_components.Graph component
in the layout, which does not support this property.
This ID was used in the callback(s) for Output(s):
var.children